# What can I use instead of the Array.prototype.indexOf method?

Tags: javascript

I want to use my own method instead of `indexOf()` method and I tried this.If i use ie 8 and earlier versions.

```js
var a = ["i", "you", "him"];
var b = "him";
var indexb;

for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
  if (b == a[i]) {
    indexb = i;
  break
  }
}

console.log(indexb) //result is 2.so true and i use i=a.length for stop.
```

This way is true or not ,i tried this for big array and i get result in 2ms

Comment: What's the question? btw, use the statement `break` to stop looping.

Comment: The `Array.prototype.indexOf` method is optimized and compiled code, why would you think your interpreted code would be faster? Also, you are using `Array.prototype.length`... Why don't you implement your own bounds checking too?

Comment: This sounds less like a question and more like a blog post.

Comment: İ create a web site and speed is very important for me.And we cant use indexOf() method in IE 8 and earlier versions.

Comment: Great, what's your question?

Comment: His asking is this code optimal to use as a Polyfill method.
I think break would be more optimal then the assignment + the extra iteration + check . Like @Ela said.

Comment: This is the Polyfill implementation of [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill)

Comment: I edited my question.This code is very useful for me and i try my own array methods.Ty all and i read that article @Ele.I want to learn only this code is good or not i get result for big arrays in 2ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make an optimization, start with the official MDN polyfill for the method, if you want to support incompatible browsers.

See: ***[MDN Web Docs - Array.prototype.indexOf() - Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill)***

You can start optimizing there.

```js
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function indexOf(member, startFrom) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError("Array.prototype.indexOf() - can't convert `" + this + "` to object");
    }
    var index = isFinite(startFrom) ? Math.floor(startFrom) : 0,
      that = this instanceof Object ? this : new Object(this),
      length = isFinite(that.length) ? Math.floor(that.length) : 0;
    if (index >= length) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (index < 0) {
      index = Math.max(length + index, 0);
    }
    if (member === undefined) {
      do {
        if (index in that && that[index] === undefined) {
          return index;
        }
      } while (++index < length);
    } else {
      do {
        if (that[index] === member) {
          return index;
        }
      } while (++index < length);
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Comment: `indexOf(item,start)` I dont need start ,so i dont need Array.prototype.indexOf().Because my code just find.

Comment: But ty for your attention.